# Executing bash then running commands in docker

Tags: bash, shell, docker

You can execute a bash shell in a docker container by using

```
sudo docker exec -it container bash
```

But I want a command that executes a bash shell in the container and then executes more commands in the bash prompt.

A command like this currently works:

```
sudo docker exec -it container touch test.txt | bash
```

However, the command I want to run in the bash prompt is only available from within the docker container, so I get an error:

```
No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to execute a command that is local to the docker container using docker exec?

Comment: The command `bash` is the `bash` of the container.  If your container does not have bash, this can actually fail (see the image `alpine`).  So if your container has some command like `git` you can do `docker exec -it container git clone https://somegit`. [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Comment: What command are you trying to run.  EVERY command executed via docker exec is inside the container.

Comment: By command do you mean bash script? As in you want to do `bash myscript.sh`?  If so you need to be aware of working directory of the container (which can be set by `WORKDIR`).  You can find it out using `pwd` by running that in the container.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose I should've read the docker docs more!

```
docker exec -it container mycommand
```

works fine! For some reason I was thinking I had to initiate a bash prompt then use other commands, my mistake.

Thanks jrbeverly and user2105103 for the explanation that "EVERY command executed via docker exec is inside the container."

In case someone is curious how to run multiple commands in a container, I'm using:

```
sudo docker exec -it container sh -c "com1 && com2 && com3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
sudo docker exec -it container bash -c "touch test.txt ; <another command>"
```

Comment: Huh? You're trying to *pipe* from `touch` into another command? That doesn't make sense -- `touch` doesn't emit anything on stdout, so there's nothing to pipe.

Comment: Perhaps you want `;` instead of `|`?